# Connection between Deligne-Mostow monodromy and Gassner representation at roots of unity of the pure braid group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, braid-groups

I am looking for a specific reference to the connection between [1] the Deligne-Mostow monodromy and [2] Gassner representation at roots of unity of the pure braid group. I have seen many references but no specific place where this is established.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Aakumadula

Comment: I would recommend looking at Thurston's paper:
http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gtm/1998/01/p025.xhtml

In particular, he proves that the reps. preserve a certain quadratic form, which you might see being preserved by the Gassner rep. too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This paper looks very interesting.

Regards,

Aakumadula 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

- Michael Kapovich, John J. Millson, *Quantization of bending deformations of polygons in Euclidean space, hypergeometric integrals and the Gassner representation*, Canadian Mathematical Bulletin, 44(1) (2001) 36-60, doi:[10.4153/CMB-2001-006-3](https://doi.org/10.4153/CMB-2001-006-3), arXiv:[math/0002222](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002222)

for the explicit relation between representations constructed via hypergeometric integrals and Gassner. We also explain the connection to [DM]. The representations we construct in the paper are mildly different from the ones in [DM], but you just have to replace our parameters $\epsilon_j=\pm 1$ with $\sqrt{-1}$ (to get [DM]).

Comment: Thanks very much. This is most helpful.

Regards,

Aakumadula